# Driving Zone Computation using Web Processing Services

Tags: wms, wfs, ogc, wps

I am currently evaluating different OGC Services(WFS,WMS and WPS) for driving zone computation.  As I am new to WPS services, I would like some suggestions regarding which OGC services to implement.

I am thinking through these issues right now:

If I use WPS to calculate driving zones, is it better to integrate this computation as Web Processing Service or to directly compute it in the App Server?  Would the client be overwhelmed or exhausted with delays in computation?

Is there any way to deal with driving zone computations that exceed some predefined computation time limit, like couple of seconds?

Also is there any issue if my background map layer is in different road network than the road network where driving zone computation is being performed?

Please correct me if my concept is misleading.

Thanks

Comment: You will need to do the geoprocessing (driving zones) on a server due to the nature and amount of processing required. Example http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/demos/geoprocessor/gp_servicearea.html Javascript code http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm

Comment: Building drive zones is computationally similar to routing, so you might try searching for people who are using WPS for routing, like [here](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/Routing-with-Web-Processing-Service-td2060303.html).

Comment: Like @Mapperz , you need to do geoprocessiong on server. I don't know any WPS driving zones services. I usually use pgrouting (http://pgrouting.org/) for this issues, but performing is not good and need a lot of resources.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is a bit old by now, I'm guessing there's increasing interest.

AFAIK, 52North's products are the state of the art on [offering WPSs based on geoprocessing](http://52north.org/communities/geoprocessing/wps/). Although the OP didn't specify the desired back end, 52North can sit on a number of platforms, including [ArcGIS Server](http://52north.org/communities/geoprocessing/wps/backends/52n-wps-ags.html).

Comment: ArcGIS Server 10.1 offers WPS as a capability of a Geoprocessing Service. So, if sitting in the Esri stack, you could implement a drivetime geoprocessing service and enable WPS on it.